# two jquery plugins use the same function name, can somehow i use them both?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have two jQuery plugins that use the same function name (bind), can i somehow use those two plugins together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function is built in to jQuery and adds an event handler to an element.

Your two plugins are not redefining the `bind` method; they're adding additional events that you can bind to.

You should be able to use them together just fine.